# When I run my code (which is about linear programming with python pulp), coulnd't get any answer

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

This is my code about minimization problem I am using anaconda spyder, when I tried to run it, program never stopped running. The main problem is about #C11 constraint, whenever I changed it into this form (which is the same on my code that I shared),  from this one `model+=(T_vars[v][i] for i in set_D for v in set_V)==0`, I cannot get any answer from the program. I want to know what is wrong about my code. I will be thankful if you could help me.

```
import pulp as plp
#import pandas as pd
model = plp.LpProblem("Ornek", plp.LpMinimize)
#sets
set_E={'3','4','5','6'} #affected area
set_S={'1','2'} #shelters
set_SE={'1','2','3','4','5','6'}
set_ED={'3','4','5','6','7'}
set_V={'1','2','3','4','5','6'} #available veicle
set_D={'7'} #set of vehicle depots
set_N={'1','2','3','4','5','6','7'} #set of all nodes in people evacuation operations
#parameters
tr={'1':{'1':0,'2':5,'3':15,'4':10,'5':5,'6':20,'7':25},
    '2':{'1':5,'2':0,'3':5,'4':10,'5':5,'6':15,'7':20},
    '3':{'1':15,'2':5,'3':0,'4':5,'5':10,'6':30,'7':20},
    '4':{'1':10,'2':10,'3':5,'4':0,'5':20,'6':25,'7':10},
    '5':{'1':5,'2':5,'3':10,'4':20,'5':0,'6':10,'7':5},
    '6':{'1':20,'2':15,'3':30,'4':25,'5':10,'6':0,'7':5},
    '7':{'1':25,'2':20,'3':20,'4':10,'5':5,'6':5,'7':0}} #transportation time from node i to node j
d={'3':30,
   '4':20,
   '5':20,
   '6':30} #demand of affected area 
c={'1':60,
   '2':50} #capacity of shelters
cap={'1':20,
     '2':20,
     '3':20,
     '4':20,
     '5':20,
     '6':20} #capacity of vehicle
t={'1':10,
   '2':10,
   '3':10,
   '4':10,
   '5':10,
   '6':10,
   '7':0}#service time at node i
Mbig=int(1000)
alpha=int(6)
#decision variables
x_vars =plp.LpVariable.dicts('Seçilen',
                             [(v,i,j) for v in set_V
                                    for i in set_N
                                    for j in set_N],
                             0,1,plp.LpBinary)
y_vars =plp.LpVariable.dicts('Seçilen2',
                             [(v,i) for v in set_V
                                    for i in set_SE],
                             0,1,plp.LpBinary) 
z_vars =plp.LpVariable.dicts('Seçilen3',set_V,0,1,plp.LpBinary)
q_vars=plp.LpVariable.dicts("Number of people picked up",(set_V,set_SE),0,None,plp.LpInteger)
T_vars=plp.LpVariable.dicts("Time",(set_V,set_N),0,None,plp.LpInteger)
#objective function
model+=plp.lpSum(T_vars[v][i] for v in set_V for i in set_SE)
         
#C1
for v in set_V:
    model += plp.lpSum(x_vars[(v,i,j)] for j in set_E for i in set_D ) == z_vars[v]   
#C2
for j in set_E:
    for v in set_V:
        model+=plp.lpSum(x_vars[(v,i,j)] for i in set_ED if i!=j )==plp.lpSum(x_vars[(v,j,i)] for i in set_SE if i!=j)
#C3
for i in set_E:
    model += plp.lpSum(q_vars[v][i] for v in set_V) == d[i]
#C4
for v in set_V:
    for i in set_SE:
        model+= cap[v]*y_vars[(v,i)]>=q_vars[v][i]

#C5
for i in set_E:
     for v in set_V:
         model += plp.lpSum(x_vars[(v,j,i)]  for j in set_ED if i!=j ) == y_vars[(v,i)]
#C6
for i in set_S:
    for v in set_V:
        model += plp.lpSum(x_vars[(v,j,i)] for j in set_SE  if i!=j ) == y_vars[(v,i)] 
#C7
for v in set_V:
    model+=plp.lpSum(q_vars[v][i] for i in set_S )==plp.lpSum(q_vars[v][i] for i in set_E)
#C8
for v in set_V:
    model += plp.lpSum(q_vars[v][i] for i in set_E) <= cap[v]*z_vars[v]
    
#C9
for i in set_S:
    model+= plp.lpSum(q_vars[v][i] for v in set_V) <= c[i]
#C10
model += plp.lpSum(z_vars[v] for v in set_V) <= 6 

#C11
for i in set_D:
    for v in set_V:
        model+=(T_vars[v][i])==0
#C12
for j in set_E:
    for v in set_V:
        for i in set_ED: 
            if i!=j:
                model+=((T_vars[v][i] + t[i] + tr[i][j])- Mbig*(1-x_vars[(v,i,j)]))<=T_vars[v][j]
#C13
for v in set_V:
    for j in set_S:
        for i in set_E:
            model+= ((T_vars[v][i] + t[i] + tr[i][j]) - Mbig*(1-x_vars[(v,i,j)]) )<=T_vars[v][j]

model.solve()                    
print("Status:", model.status)
print((model.objective))
```

Comment: I suspect the two formulations are very different. Write out the lp file to compare. To see why the second formulation fails to solve, make sure to generate and study the solver log. That may be a bit tricky, but you can always generate an lp or mps file and run the solver from a console or terminal.

Comment: This code `model+=(T_vars[v][i] for i in set_D for v in set_V)==0` will not add constraints to your `model`. The expression in brackets will be a generator type object, so it would need to be operated on (for example summed) to crate an expression that can be used in a constraint. As it is I think it will override your model objective function.